# Using typescript and styled-component when extending third-party component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

how can I get type hints for extended styled-component props in vscode? I don't talk about style's props but about component's props.

When I extend my own component with styled(), type hint for props work perfectly. But when I use third-party component inside styled(), vscode don't give me any props hint.

```ts
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

const InputElement = styled(NumberFormat)`
  border: 5px solid #eddcc7;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .75em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
`

const Input: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    // Get type hints for below extended styled component
    <InputElement />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

What I do wrong and what can I do correct?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that the `styled-component` is not picking up properly props from the `react-number-format` library. The issue might be that `react-number-format`'s default exported component's props, [`NumberFormatProps`](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format/blob/master/typings/number_format.d.ts#L76) contain the `[key: string]: any` field, which causes `styled-component` to break its type inference.

The issue can be resolved if you instead make a type from the `NumberFormat` component, which will instead have the [`NumberFormatPropsBase`](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format/blob/master/typings/number_format.d.ts#L26) props.

Here's an example:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import NumberFormat, { NumberFormatPropsBase } from "react-number-format";

const InputElement = styled<React.ComponentType<NumberFormatPropsBase>>(
  NumberFormat
)`
  border: 5px solid #eddcc7;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
`;
```

If you're using the `NumberFormat` styled component in multiple places, I also recommend you to extract to a different file:

*MyNumberFormat.tsx*

```js
import NumberFormat, { NumberFormatPropsBase } from "react-number-format";

export default NumberFormat as React.ComponentType<NumberFormatPropsBase>;

export * from "react-number-format";
```

And then use it from there:

```js
import NumberFormat from "./MyNumberFormat";

const InputElement = styled(NumberFormat)`
  border: 5px solid #eddcc7;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
`;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is solution what I was looking for. You make my day better. ❤

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found one of possible solutions.

```ts
import React from "react";
// Import StyledComponent
import styled, { StyledComponent } from "styled-components";
// Import props (in this package works base)
import NumberFormat, { NumberFormatPropsBase } from "react-number-format";

// Setup type annotation with StyledComponent like this
const InputElement: StyledComponent<
  React.FC<NumberFormatPropsBase>, 
  any, 
  {}, 
  never
> = styled(NumberFormat)`
  border: 5px solid #eddcc7;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .75em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
`

const Input: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    // Now you get type hint for this styled component
    <InputElement />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

I describe solution in code with comments.

I don't know if it's best practice but it works for me.
Now, my vscode (and also other IDE as webstom) suggest me props.